# Bash - Get Sudoer Username?

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo, root, users

Say I have the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $( whoami )
```

This is what it outputs with and without sudo:

```
alix@netbook:~$ ./test.sh 
alix
alix@netbook:~$ sudo ./test.sh 
root
```

The script executes several commands that require superuser priviledges, but I also want to add the original executing user to a group. Is there any command that returns `alix` if I run `sudo ./test.sh`?

Comment: Just noticed that this would better fit Unix.SE, feel free to migrate if needed.

Answer (score 5):

Found the solution in a [related answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/30006/9018):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $( whoami )
echo $SUDO_USER
```

And the output:

```
alix@netbook:~$ ./test.sh 
alix

alix@netbook:~$ sudo ./test.sh 
root
alix
```